# What's the rate of maturity for gnomes?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, aging

I'm trying to create a gnome character. The 5e player handbook states that gnomes can live to 350-400 years, and I columbused a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Education) that states gnomes start school at age 30.

But what are the age ranges for gnome children and adolescents? And at what age do they typically start/stop having children?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen someone play a mature gnome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## They become mature like humans do. They start having children around 40.

> **Age.** Gnomes mature at the same rate humans do, and most are expected
> to settle down into an adult life by around age 40. (PHB p.36, "Gnome Traits")

> **Age.** Humans reach adulthood in their late teens [...] (PHB p.31, "Human Traits")

Sadly, I couldn't find when they stop reproducing in 5e. However in 5e they age similarly to how they did in 3.5e.

> | Race | Middle Age | Old | Venerable | Maximum Age |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Gnome | 100 years | 150 years | 200 years | +3d% years |
>
> (from the [3.5e SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/description.htm#age))

**If it is not a problem to use 3.5 source, they would stop reproducing around 100 years(the risk of having unhealthy child is bigger with middle aged parents).**

Comment: So both races hit maturity around age 18-22, but Gnomes are still "kids" until age 40. Am I reading that right?

Comment: Yeah, seems like physical maturity is around age 20, then social maturity at age 40.

Comment: @miltonaut ahh okay, so more or less like Hobbits (33rd birthday is "becoming a man")